# integrate Dropzone.js in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, dropzone.js

In my laravel 5.2 project I need to create a multi file upload area. I choose Dropzone.js
Now my problem is how to use this plugin with laravel.

this is my view:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Facebook:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="facebook" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Twitter:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="twitter" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="video" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Video:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="video" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--File Upload-->


        <div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFileUpload">
        </div>



 <script type="text/javascript">
        var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
        var token = "{{ Session::getToken() }}";
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
         var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
             url: baseUrl+"/dropzone/uploadFiles",
             params: {
                _token: token
              }
         });
         Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
            paramName: "file",
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            accept: function(file, done) {

            },
          };
     </script>
```

my controller:

```
    public function store(SpotFormRequest $request) {
     $user = Auth::user();
     $role = $user->role;
     if($role === 'manager'){
         $idagent = 1;
         $idmanager = $user->id;
     }
     else{
         $idagent=$user->id;
         $idmanager=0;
     }


    $spot = new Spot(array(
        'agent_id'=>$idagent,
        'manager_id'=>$idmanager,
        'name' => $request->get('spotname'),
        'address' => $request->get('address'),
        'zip' => $request->get('zip'),
        'city'=>$request->get('city_id'),
        'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
        'mobile' => $request->get('mobile'),
    ));
    $spot->save();

    return redirect('/administrator/spot-new')->with('status', 'Your spot has been created!');
}
```

I need to integrate the upload in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing Dropzone in Laravel project could be a bit tricky

This is a step by step [tutorial](http://learninglaravel.net/laravel-5-and-dropzonejs-auto-image-uploads-with-removal-links/link) which I found extremely  helpful

This tutorial covers:

1. Auto image upload
2. Remove images directly from Dropzone preview with    AJAX request
3. Image counter for uploaded images
4. Saving images as full    size and icon size versions Using
5. Image Intervention package for    resizing and image encoding
6. Saving image data to database
7. Unique filenames for images on server side